# Flow Diagramming Software with SQL Server Connectivity

Tags: windows, sql-server

I am looking for software that can connect to an MSSQL Database and download a diagram. We are running SQL Server 2014. You used to be able to do this in Visio Professional, however they have discontinued this in Visio 2013- which of course is needed for SQL 2014. With Visio, you used to be able to connect to the SQL database and it would allow you to automatically create a diagram based on the selected tables.

What software can do this?

**Notes**:

- I want this software for Windows.
- Also looking for a possible replacement for Visio so if it has the other tools- flow diagrams and process diagrams that would be great.

Comment: Is the diagram one that is stored on the server or one generated to represent what is stored on the server?

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of solutions utilising [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org) listed [here](http://www.graphviz.org/content/resources).  This may provide you with a good starting point.